# How would I parse requested cookies using puppeteer and save them to a variable to be called later?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

im trying to parse specific valus from these cookies and save them to a variable to be used later but I cant seem to figure it out. Im using puppeteer to login and then request the cookies after logging in.

Im using puppeteers cookie request like this.

```
const returnedCookies = await page.cookies()
console.log(returnedCookies);
```

Which outputs this and a few other strings. But I wanted to know how to get the value of that "mystate" and store it into a variable.

```
{
    name: 'mystate',
    value: '1614736342244',
    domain: '.target.com',
    path: '/',
    expires: -1,
    size: 20,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    session: true,
    sameParty: false
  },
```

Any input at all would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Isn't the value of `mystate` the property `value` with `'1614736342244'`?

Comment: Yes it is but I wanted to get that value into a var. Like the 161... value into a var!

Answer (score 1):

In your case `returnedCookies` is an array of objects. You can use [`find` method for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search through an array for one result:

```
const returnedCookies = await page.cookies();
const cookieNeeded = returnedCookies.find((cookie) => cookie.name ==='mystate');

let value = null;

// If the desired cookie is found in the array, get its value
if(typeof cookieNeeded !== 'undefined') {
  value = cookieNeeded.value;
}

// If the needed cookie wasn't found `value` will be null
console.log(value);
```